# how does MySQL know which partition to look up?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

Let's analyse the simplest possible example of MySQL paritioning by hash (slightly modified version of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id INT,
    year_col INT
);

ALTER TABLE t1
    PARTITION BY HASH(year_col)
    PARTITIONS 8;
```

Let's say we put there millions of records. The question is - if a specific query comes (e.g. `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE year_col = 5`) then how does MySQL know which partition to look up? There are 8 partitions. I guess that the hash function is calculated and MySQL recognizes that it matches thepartitioning key and then MySQL knows which one that is. But what is the query is `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE year_col IN (5, 45, 5435)`? How about other non-trivial queries? Is there any general algorithm for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [*Partition pruning*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-pruning.html):

> The optimizer can perform pruning whenever a `WHERE` condition can be reduced to either one of the following two cases:
>
> - ***partition_column* = constant**
> - ***partition_column* IN (*constant1, constant2, ..., constantN*)**
>
> In the first case, the optimizer simply evaluates the partitioning expression for the value given, determines which partition contains that value, and scans only this partition. (...)
>
> In the second case, the optimizer evaluates the partitioning expression for each value in the list, creates a list of matching partitions, and then scans only the partitions in this partition list. (...)
>
> MySQL can apply partition pruning to `SELECT`, `DELETE`, and `UPDATE` statements. `INSERT` statements currently cannot be pruned.
>
> Pruning can also be applied to short ranges, which the optimizer can convert into equivalent lists of values. (...)

Comment: not an easy topic, but your answer is precisely what I needed, thank you.

Comment: Will it really do such for "short ranges" and non-RANGE partitioning??